# Iterate over numpy array to get sub-arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given the following numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

what iterable would return sub-arrays of length `x` from `arr`? (Given that `len(arr)` is a multiple of `x`)

```
x = 2
sub_arrays = [sub_arr for sub_arr in iterable(arr, x)]
```

> sub_arrays = [ np.ndarray( [0, 1] ), np.ndarray( [2, 3] ), np.ndarray( [4, 5] ) ]

I know that array slicing is possible with `start`, `stop`, and `step` arguments, but that returns individual elements:

```
x = 2
sub_elements = [sub_elem for sub_elem in arr[::x]]
```

> sub_elements = [0, 2, 4]

Comment: `np.split(arr, 3)` ?

Comment: `arr.reshape(-1,2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate over a numpy array and obtain sub-arrays of a specific length, you can use the numpy.reshape function. By reshaping the array with the desired shape, you can obtain sub-arrays of the specified length. Here's an example:
import numpy as np

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
x = 2

sub_arrays = np.reshape(arr, (-1, x))
```

In this example, np.reshape is used to reshape the array arr into sub-arrays of length x. The parameter -1 in the reshape function allows numpy to automatically determine the appropriate size for that dimension. The resulting sub_arrays will be a 2D numpy array containing the sub-arrays:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

You can also convert each sub-array into a separate ndarray if desired:

```
sub_arrays = [np.array(sub_arr) for sub_arr in sub_arrays]
```

This will give you a list of numpy arrays as you specified:

```
[array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]), 
array([4, 5])]
```

Have a good coding!

Comment: Can you prove that your solution is faster than @AhmedAEK's?

Answer (score 2):

you should use [np.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html)

```py
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
x = 2
sub_elements = np.array_split(arr, len(arr)/x)
```

```
[ array([0,1]), array([2,3]), array([4,5]) ]
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thank you =) BTW, to make your answer extra clear you should rename sub_elements to sub_arrays.

Comment: I have to wait another 3 minutes before accepting =)

Comment: What is faster? `np.array_split(arr, len(arr)/2)` or `arr.reshape(-1, 2)`?

Comment: @FlorentH `np.array_split` creates a list, while `arr.reshape(-1, 2)` doesn't create anything, it just changes the size field, so `arr.reshape` is faster, however if you are going to make a list out of the reshaped array then they perform in exactly equal time, as exactly the same code is going to run, so you should probably accept the other answer.

Comment: Thank you for your honesty Ahmed!